# How to get Microsoft bot welcome message in speech?

Tags: botframework, chatbot

I want my welcome message to be spoken by bot. I have used this code in my message controller, but this could not help-

```
 else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
            {
                if (message.MembersAdded.Any(o => o.Id == message.Recipient.Id))
                {
                    ConnectorClient client = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(message.ServiceUrl));

                    var reply = message.CreateReply();


                    reply.Text = "Hey there! I provide information on weather, stock and tableau. Ask me anything and I will try to answer";
                    reply.Speak = "Hey there! I provide information on weather, stock and tableau. Ask me anything and I will try to answer";
                    reply.InputHint = InputHints.AcceptingInput;
                    await client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Which channel are you using?

Comment: i am using Direct line

Comment: Is this v3 or v4?